Extract all possible combinations of values and column names in R
I have a table with some data, let's assume it looks like that:
A   B   C   
X   1   0
Y   2   5

So columns are named A, B and C and the data frame has 2 rows.
I need to find out what value in columns B and C matches what column name and value from column A, so the result would look like some table with only one column:
BX1
BY2
CX0
CY5

So each row would have an information in the following order: cell's column name, matching value from column A for this cell, value in the cell. How can I do this?

> unlist(Map(paste0, names(d[-1]), d[1], d[-1]))
   B1    B2    C1    C2 
"BX1" "BY2" "CX0" "CY5" 

maybe, or
> unlist(Map(paste0, names(d[-1]), d[1], d[-1])) |> as.matrix()
   [,1] 
B1 "BX1"
B2 "BY2"
C1 "CX0"
C2 "CY5"

or
> data.frame(foo=unlist(Map(paste0, names(d[-1]), d[1], d[-1])), row.names=NULL)
  foo
1 BX1
2 BY2
3 CX0
4 CY5


A tidyverse approach, there WILL be a simpler way with base R I'm sure:.
#mock data
df3 <- read.table(text = "A   B   C   
                          X   1   0
                          Y   2   5", header = TRUE)

df3 |> 
  pivot_longer(c(-A), names_to = "col2", values_to = "col3") |> 
  mutate(A = paste0(col2, A, col3), .keep = "unused") |> 
  arrange(A)

Yields:
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  A    
  <chr>
1 BX1  
2 BY2  
3 CX0  
4 CY5

